# javascript nested template strings

Tags: javascript, string, templates

In javascript, assume some data definitions similar to these ones:

```
y='${z}' 
z='hi' // y and z can be constants, or read from file, or ...
x=`===${y}===`
```

Is it possible to write a "simple" javascript code that finishes with "x" being equal to "===hi===" instead of "===${z}===" ?

( note the steps to find the target result are "===${y}===" => "===${z}===" => "===hi===" ).

That is, could behavior of template strings (replacement of ${k} by k value) be used in a "loop" until no more ${} to replace in the resulting string ?

Better if the solution allows data be stored in a map instead of in the current context. That is, starting from

```
data = { x : '===${y}===', y: '${y}', z='hi' }
```

the call:

```
myFunction(data, 'x')
```

should return '===hi==='.

Comment: When you say "recursive", can you show an example of this? How should a string like `===${${y}y}===` be interpreted?

Comment: If you set `y='${z}'` to `y=\`${z}\``, it is ok. Print `x` and it will print the expected result.

Comment: @ggorlen: if necessary, we can assume that inside ${} only a valid js identifier will be present. however, the best sequence for the case you present is ===${${y}y}=== -> ===${${z}y}=== -> ===${hiy}=== -> ======

Comment: @sjahan: I know, I will clarify the question.

Comment: About having everything in the same object, I doubt you can do it without making something fishy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your explanation. Can you edit your post to clarify exactly how the recursion should work on a few examples?

Comment: @ggorlen: question edited

Comment: Thanks--it looks like you removed the recursive requirement?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [nested templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Nesting_templates), [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), or [raw strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using `eval`.
Below code show the way to do this job in global context.

```
x = '===${y}===';
y = '${z}';
z = 'hi';

template = x;
result = x;
do {
    template = result;
    result = eval("`"+template+"`");
} while(result != template);
result;
```

In non global context, you can create a function as a string and pass to the `eval` function. Below code show how to do this.

```
let data = { x : '===${y}===', y: '${z}', z : 'hi' }
let myFunction = function(data, member) {
    let env = ["(function() { \n"];
    for(let prop in data){
        env.push("\tlet ");
        env.push(prop);
        env.push(" = '");
        env.push(data[prop]);
        env.push("';\n");
    }
    let template = data[member]
    let result  = data[member];
    do {
        template = result;
        env.push("\treturn `"+template+"`;\n");
        env.push("})();");
        result = eval(env.join(""));
        env.pop();
        env.pop();
    } while(result!=template);

    return result;
}
myFunction(data, "x");
```